# Not able to load German words corpus using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to figure out if word is valid in German or English language using nltk, for English its working fine but I am getting this error for German:  "OSError: No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Usama\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\corpora\words\de" I don't know the reason for this error and need some help to fix it. Following is my code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')


def is_valid_word(word, language):
    if language == "english":
        words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words('en'))
    elif language == "german":
        print("HERE")
        words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words('de'))
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid language: {language}")
    return word.lower() in words


word = "hello"
language = "english"

if is_valid_word(word, language):
    print(f"{word} is a valid {language} word")
else:
    print(f"{word} is not a valid {language} word")

word = "hallo"
language = "german"

if is_valid_word(word, language):
    print(f"{word} is a valid {language} word")
else:
    print(f"{word} is not a valid {language} word")
```

Answer (score 2):

`from nltk.corpus import words` does not include German as a `fileid` (i.e. `print(words.fileids()`):

```
['en', 'en-basic']
```

Only English.

Comment: its now showing invalid words as valid words as well.

Comment: @Usama Hameed you're right, I just edited my answer.

Comment: what should I do for German then?

Comment: There are some capabilities for using German (https://data-dive.com/german-nlp-binary-text-classification-of-reviews-part1/) but I can't find the equivalent for `nltk.corpus`'s `words`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@ori-yaden pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75906626/610569) only `en` and `en-basic` is supported by the `nltk.corpus.words` interface.

If you need something more multilingual, perhaps you can consider something like

- https://huggingface.co/datasets/oscar-corpus or
- https://huggingface.co/datasets/wikipedia

```
pip install -U apache_beam
pip install -U datasets
pip install -U nltk
pip install -U tqdm
```

For german try this:

```
from itertools import chain

from tqdm import tqdm
#import nltk
#nltk.download('popular')

from nltk import word_tokenize
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("wikipedia", "20220301.de")


num_texts = len(dataset['train']) # outputs: 2,665,357


# Pick the first 100,000 texts
de_words = set(chain(*(word_tokenize(dataset['train'][i]['text']) for i in tqdm(range(100_000)))))
```

There are other things like lowercase, lemmatize/stemming etc. other than `word_tokenize` to consider but hopefully the data source above will be a good start to find words in the language you need beyond the English words that `nltk.corpus.words` provides.